# Emacs init file with yasnippets and magit submodule update error

Tags: magit, yasnippet, use-package, process

I have cloned [yasnippets repo](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/) repo in `~/.emacs.d/yasnippet-snippets`.
I would like to synchronize it each time I start Emacs (btw, it would be nice to do it only if there is a connection available), my current (pretty raw) code is:

```
;; ~/.emacs
(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  (cd "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet-snippets")
  (magit-submodule-update)
  (yas-reload-all)
  (cd "~/"))
```

But I am getting this error in `*Messages*`, probably because it changes directory before finishing the *magit* process:

```
error in process sentinel: user-error: Not inside a Git repository
error in process sentinel: Not inside a Git repository
```

*Using: [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package)

Comment: Both `cd` and `magit-submodule-update` are intended for interactive use. I would start by replacing `cd` with `(setq default-directory ...)`, then add debug statements that print the current-buffer and default-directory to see what's going on.

Comment: `magit-submodule-update` runs git asynchronously and returns before it finishes, so putting the `yas-reload-all` after it will not guarantee that the updated snippets are loaded. Also, yasnippet-snippets repo doesn't have submodules, did you (mean to) clone yasnippet or yasnippet-snippets repo?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use Magit at all here as that would force you to always load it at startup.

Comment: @npostavs thanks, instead of using *magit* I ended up using *git* directly as suggested in the answer. Also, I was following the advice in the official [docs](https://github.com/AndreaCrotti/yasnippet-snippets/) on how to update the repo: `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: The yasnippet repo has yasnippet-snippets as a submodule, so you should run `subdmodule update` in the yasnippet repo to update yasnippet-snippets. If you did actually clone the yasnippet repo, then it's a bit confusing to have it in a directory named yasnippet-snippets.

Comment: @npostavs that makes more sense, I was doing it wrong, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would probably work:

```
(use-package yasnippet
  :init
  (let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/yasnippet-snippets/"))
    (call-process "git" nil nil nil "pull")))
```

Comment: @marcanuy why are you suggesting to replace the `let` with a `setq`? Doing so would permanently changes the `default-directory` of the `*scratch*` buffer.